Not able to use the Reference Variable to access methods in Intellij Maven project
I'm new to coding and I will try to be as specific as possible.
I will attach images for the steps I performed.

I created a maven project in IntelliJ. New Project and what I selected to create the project
The POM.xml file which was created automatically after I created the project. Auto generated pom.xml
I added the Selenium and Testng dependencies to the POM.xml and removed the JUNIT dependency as I wont be using it. Testng and Selenium Dependency
The Libraries are added to the project.
When I create a WebDriver class reference in the Test.java its give me suggestions. I create a reference variable. WebDriver reference variable
When I try to use the reference variable, it does not work. It wont give me any suggestions nor can I use any methods with it. WebDriver Reference Variable which can't be used

I'm not sure why this is happening and I have been trying to figure out what wrong with no luck.

I have tried deleting the class and creating a new one in both main/java and test/java
I have tried deleting the project and creating a new one.
Tried rebuilding the project.
Removing the dependencies and adding them again.

Can anyone please help me with this? I have not used IntelliJ before and I'm not sure why it keeps happening.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

@seenukarthi I was going to add it, but there seems to be a lot of images that I have added, and adding that as a code would have eventually made the text too long. Thats why I opted for images instead.

The disadvantage of images is their difficulty copying the content, and trying the code or searching for the error will be difficult.

When you enter driver, the suggestions are about completing that word. When you want to access a member , you must enter driver. (with a dot after the variable) I bet, you’ll see member suggestions then.

@Holger Even if I enter driver. it still wont give me any suggestions. I have reinstalled the whole system as well. Nothing works.

The problem is that you are typing code outside of a method. Your code is in the area reserved for class variable definitions, etc.
Change your code to the below and it should work.
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class AppTest {
    private int i = 0; // class variables/fields go here, not code.

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "https://www.google.com";

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(url);

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea[name='q']")).sendKeys("Selenium/r/n");
    }
}

